# Add a space in a javascript line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code:

```
var bgposh = "-37";


$(element).find('.toggle_box').css({'-webkit-transition': 'background-position 0.2s linear', 'background-position': '147px "+ bgposh +"px'});
```

but the background position does not get set. I think it is because there is no space between px and bgposh. How can I add one? I tried + + but that does not seem to work.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can't mix single quotes with double quotes. Javascript supports both, but if you open a string literal with a single quote, then you also have to close with one.

Comment: why did I get a -1? was this not well asked? or am I too stupid to not deserve one? :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little syntax error i think with your bgposh variable

```
$(element).find('.toggle_box').css(
   {'-webkit-transition': 'background-position 0.2s linear', 
    'background-position': '147px '+ bgposh +'px'
   });
```

Comment: thank you sir, this fixes the problem :). I ddidn't know there was a difference between " and ' but thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: There is actually **no difference**. Your problem was just that you started a string with a single quote and attempted to end it with a double quote for some reason.

Comment: oh yeah now that you explained it i feel really stupid :p thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is because with this code you have set `background-position` to `147px "+ bgposh +"px`.

You have wrong quotes. The correct version looks like this (notice different quotes):

```
$(element).find('.toggle_box').css({
    '-webkit-transition': 'background-position 0.2s linear',
    'background-position': '147px ' + bgposh + 'px'
});
```

Comment: let's assume that var bgposh = "-37"

Comment: You may assume what you want to, the double-quotes still be wrong there

Comment: @SnippetSpace Lets look at the example: [jsfiddle.net/NfgPf](http://jsfiddle.net/NfgPf/)